# What are the rate limits for Image-Charts?

Tags: image-charts

We are using [Image-Charts](https://www.image-charts.com/) as a replacement for Google Image Charts for a dashboard.

When attempting to render a large number of charts, our requests begin to receive `429 Too Many Requests` errors.

We tried searching [the documentation](https://documentation.image-charts.com/), but could not find anything about limits.

Are you able to share any limits? Are there different limits between the free and paid plans?

Comment: The 429 Error may havbe additional Ratelimit Info

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Disclaimer: I'm Image-Charts founder*

Current rate limit is at 80 requests per second. 
If you go over that point and need a custom plan please contact our support :)